# How do I open a new form and query the database at the same time?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error, aura-attribute, lightninginput, aura-if

On the current page, I have a "New" button that opens a new form, where I need to fill in the "Account" field as well. And I want to get a list of "Account" values ​​in the same method that opens the form. Why does the error occur if I add the action "component.getListAccounts ();" (which loads the list of accounts) into the "openForm" method? If I remove this action, then the form will open, but I will not have a list of accounts to select.

**//cmp**

```
    <aura:component>
  
    <aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="List"/>
    
    <aura:method name="getListAccounts" action="{!c.getListAccounts}" 
                 description="loading a list of accounts to select when adding a new contact"/>
        
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">
...
                                <lightning:combobox aura:id="contact"
                                                    label="Account"
                                                    placeholder="Select account"
                                                    value="{!v.contact.AccountId}"
                                                    options="{!v.accounts}"  
                                                    onchange="{!c.selectAccount}"/>
...
        </aura:if>
        
        <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-m-top--medium slds-m-left--medium"
                          label="New" onclick="{!c.openForm}" />
 ...
</aura:component>
```

**//js**

```
getListAccounts : function(component, event) {
        //show spinner message
      component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-show');
        var action = component.get("c.getListAccounts");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            //hide spinner when response coming from server 
          component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-hide');
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.accounts", response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                console.log('Problem saving accounts, response state: ' + state);
            }
            else {
                console.log('Unknown problem, response state: ' + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
openForm : function (component, event, helper){
        // for Display Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "true"
        component.set("v.isOpen", true);
        component.getListAccounts();
},
```

**//apxc**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Map<String, String>> getListAccounts(){
    
    List<Account> AccountList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
    List<Map<String, String>> options = new List<Map<String, String>>();
    Integer I = 0;
    for (Account ac : AccountList) {
        options.add(new Map<String, String>());
        options.get(I).put('label',ac.Name);
        options.get(I).put('value',ac.Id);
        I = I + 1;
    }
    return options;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You seem to have 2 questions here, 1 about the error, and another about how to do something. I would suggest you revise your post and ask 1 questions with enough details to provide an answer.

Comment: I tried to fix my question.